# Asp.Net API HTTP PUT/DELETE result in sign in popup

Tags: api, authentication, put

A few days ago, I have hosted an Asp.Net WebForms (.Net Framework 4.72) application on IONOS, I am using ApiController to create/update/delete data. It's OK to use post, but when I used PUT and DELETE Ajax request, it popup this

[image]

The request is something like this https://partnering.linkedbio.eu/api/customer/delete/5. Seems to me it was turned into a Windows Authentication request. I searched the net, but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help?

Regards

Tom

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought it's clear. When I used PUT/DELETE Ajax call to Web API, I don't want the Sign in pop up to show.